# Why validation pop up is not going even it falls true in HTML5 validation

Tags: jquery, html

In my task I need to put html 5 validation. Actually I don't have my submit option inside my form.So i just added as "disply:none".And am triggering that submit option from outside click option since HTML 5 validation works in click "submit". One more thing is I should add custom validation message.The messages coming properly but while entering text after added custom message dynamically its working ugly.

```
<form id="myform"  method="post" action="#" onSubmit="javascript:return false;" >
<input type="text" id="myID" required>
     <input type="text"  id="secId" required>
<input type="submit" id='formSubmit' style="display:none">
```

**Jquery code**

```
    function checkValidation(element){    
    var flag = true;
    element.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!element.validity.valid && element.validity.valueMissing) {
        element.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
        flag = false;
    } else if(element.validity.patternMismatch){  
        element.setCustomValidity("PLease enter correct format");  
        flag = false;
    } else {
        element.setCustomValidity("");
    }
    if(!flag){
        $('#formSubmit').click();
        //if(!$("#myform")[0].checkValidity()) return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    } 
}
$('#butId').click(function(){
                var $inputs = $('#myform :input');
                var formData ={};

                $inputs.each(function(e) {
                        formData[this.name] = $(this).val();
                        var flag = checkValidation(this);
                        if(!flag){
                        return false;               
                       }                        
                    });                 

            });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dtk5/1/)

Comment: You realize the return false inside the each isn't canceling the click, right?

Comment: Ya.If i submit it returns the error but even i enter right value in field its keep on populating until i click some where else.

Comment: I updated the code..please check it